# How to include modules for code coverage for unit testing?

Tags: intern

My assumption is that any module tested using Intern will automatically be covered by Istanbul's code coverage. For reasons unknown to me, my module is not being included.

I am:

- running Intern 1.6.2 (installed with npm locally)
- testing NodeJS code
- using callbacks, not promises
- using CommonJS modules, not AMD modules

Directory Structure (only showing relevant files):

```
plister
|
|--libraries
|  |--file-type-support.js
|
|--tests
|  |--intern.js
|  |--unit
|     |--file-type-support.js
|
|--node_modules
   |--intern
```

plister/tests/intern.js

```
define({
    useLoader: {
        'host-node': 'dojo/dojo'
    },
    loader: {
        packages: [
            {name: 'libraries', location: 'libraries'}
        ]        
    },
    reporters: ['console'],
    suites: ['tests/unit/file-type-support'],
    functionalSuites: [],
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(tests|node_modules)\//
});
```

plister/tests/unit/file-type-support.js

```
define([
    'intern!bdd',
    'intern/chai!expect',
    'intern/dojo/node!fs',
    'intern/dojo/node!path',
    'intern/dojo/node!stream-equal',
    'intern/dojo/node!../../libraries/file-type-support'
], function (bdd, expect, fs, path, streamEqual, fileTypeSupport) {
    'use strict';

    bdd.describe('file-type-support', function doTest() {
        bdd.it('should show that the example output.plist matches the ' + 
                'temp.plist generated by the module', function () {
            var deferred  = this.async(),
                input     = path.normalize('tests/resources/input.plist'),
                output    = path.normalize('tests/resources/output.plist'),
                temporary = path.normalize('tests/resources/temp.plist');

            // Test deactivate function by checking output produced by 
            // function against test output.
            fileTypeSupport.deactivate(fs.createReadStream(input), 
                    fs.createWriteStream(temporary), 
                    deferred.rejectOnError(function onFinish() {
                streamEqual(fs.createReadStream(output), 
                        fs.createReadStream(temporary), 
                        deferred.callback(function checkEqual(error, equal) {
                    expect(equal).to.be.true;    
                }));
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

Output:

```
PASS: main - file-type-support - should show that the example output.plist matches the temp.plist generated by the module (29ms)
1/1 tests passed
1/1 tests passed
```

Output (on failure):

```
FAIL: main - file-type-support - should show that the example output.plist matches the temp.plist generated by the module (30ms)
AssertionError: expected true to be false
AssertionError: expected true to be false
0/1 tests passed
0/1 tests passed
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Output (after removing excludeInstrumentation):

```
PASS: main - file-type-support - should show that the example output.plist matches the temp.plist generated by the module (25ms)
1/1 tests passed
1/1 tests passed

------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
File                                      |   % Stmts |% Branches |   % Funcs |   % Lines |
------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
   node_modules/intern/                   |        70 |        50 |       100 |        70 |
      chai.js                             |        70 |        50 |       100 |        70 |
   node_modules/intern/lib/               |     79.71 |     42.86 |     72.22 |     79.71 |
      Test.js                             |     79.71 |     42.86 |     72.22 |     79.71 |
   node_modules/intern/lib/interfaces/    |        80 |        50 |     63.64 |        80 |
      bdd.js                              |       100 |       100 |       100 |       100 |
      tdd.js                              |     76.19 |        50 |     55.56 |     76.19 |
   node_modules/intern/lib/reporters/     |     56.52 |        35 |     57.14 |     56.52 |
      console.js                          |     56.52 |        35 |     57.14 |     56.52 |
   node_modules/intern/node_modules/chai/ |      37.9 |      8.73 |     26.38 |     39.34 |
      chai.js                             |      37.9 |      8.73 |     26.38 |     39.34 |
   tests/unit/                            |       100 |       100 |       100 |       100 |
      file-type-support.js                |       100 |       100 |       100 |       100 |
------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
All files                                 |     42.14 |     11.35 |     33.45 |     43.63 |
------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

My module passes the test and I can make it fail too. It just will not show up in the code coverage. I have done the tutorial hosted on GitHub without any problems.

I tried dissecting the Istanbul and Intern dependencies. I place a `console.log` where it seems files to be covered go through, but my module doesn't get passed. I have tried every variation of `deferred.callback` and `deferred.rejectOnError` with no difference to the code coverage.

Also, any feedback on my use of `deferred.callback` and `deferred.rejectOnError` will be greatly appreciated. I am still a little uncertain on their usage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Intern 1.6, only `require('vm').runInThisContext` is hooked to add code coverage data, not `require`. Instrumentation of `require` was added in Intern 2.0.

The use of callback/rejectOnError in the above code is correct.

Comment: Just so I can articulate a clear request in the issue tracker, I am asking for code coverage support for CommonJS modules?

Comment: Yes sir! That would be it.